# React-bootstrap form fails to render

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've created simple ReactJS component with react-bootstrap form like this

```
import React from "react"; 
import Form from "react-bootstrap/lib/Form"; 
import Button from "react-bootstrap/lib/Button";

export default class TestForm extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                    </Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        );
    } 
}
```

But when I call it in my code I got error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TestForm`.
```

What can cause this type of error?

Comment: What can cause it? Not importing (or exporting) something correctly, like the message says. For example, the docs for react-bootstrap don’t import from lib, e.g., the docs show "import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'"

Comment: But what I have to import? There is only two bootstrap components and all of them imported. I call this component in my Router component, but don't think that it is matter because other my components work fine

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: 4-th version of bootstrap

Comment: Care to show us how to you import `TestForm` component in your app ?

Comment: It seems that I mislead you about my bootstrap version. In package.json it ```"react-bootstrap": "^0.33.0"```. This means that I have bootstrap v.3. Could you suggest me how to install bootstrap v.4?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, seems insane

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your bootstrap import to the following

```
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```